# Where are the SFDP tables stored?

Tags: flash

For context, I'm learning about the boot process of Intel devices.

> SFDP standard provides a consistent method of describing the functional and feature capabilities of Serial Flash devices in a standard set of internal parameter tables. These parameter tables can be interrogated by host system software to enable adjustments needed to accommodate divergent features from multiple vendors
>
> https://www.macronix.com/Lists/ApplicationNote/Attachments/1870/AN114v1-SFDP%20Introduction.pdf

From what I know, the initial Intel CSME firmware loaded from the on-die ROM will read the SFDP to determine how to read the SPI flash so it can then read the *Intel Flash Descriptor* (IFD) from offset 0 to locate the Intel CSME region and load the Intel ME firmware in the on-die SRAM of the Intel CSME micro-controller.

My question is : when a firmware makes a query to read the SFDP (`0x5A`), what does it mean? Where does the answer come from? SFDP tables needs to be stored somewhere.

My guess would be that they are stored on a dedicated location of the SPI Flash but I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Definition of SFDP tables from the point of view of the flash

The following part of the answer addresses the question title of *Where are the SFDP tables stored?*

From reading the [SERIAL FLASH DISCOVERABLE PARAMETERS (SFDP) JESD216F.02](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/docs/jesd216b) Jedec standard the *Security* requirements include:

> - The SFDP and flash memory address must never overlap.
> - Writes to SFDP tables must be permanently disabled before the memory device is released to a customer by the memory vendor factory.

Which means potentially SFDP tables:

1. Could be implemented as ROM in the SPI flash devices, since presumably the contents of the SFDP tables won't change unless the mask revision of the SPI flash device is updated.
2. Or some form of write-once memory programmed during device manufacture.
3. Or a special area of flash which can only be programmed during device manufacture

Macronix provide reference designs for some of their memory devices. E.g. [MX25L128356, Verilog, v1.0b.zip](https://www.mxic.com.tw/Lists/TechDoc/Attachments/10369/MX25L128356,%20Verilog,%20v1.0b.zip) for the [128-Mibit CMOS Serial NOR Flash Memory](https://www.mxic.com.tw/Lists/Datasheet/Attachments/8923/MX25L128356,%203V,%20128Mb,%20v1.0.pdf). The reference design contains:

- A Behavioral Verilog Model for the SPI flash device.
- An input file for the Behavioral Verilog Model which defines the contents of the SFDP tables.

Such reference designs can serve as an example of how the SFDP tables may be accessed, albeit the actual implementation may vary between devices / manufacturers.

### What the Intel CSME firmware uses the SFDP tables for

The following part of the answer is in response the following in the question body:

> My question is : when a firmware makes a query to read the SFDP (`0x5A`), what does it mean? Where does the answer come from?

The SFDP tables are a Jedec standard for firmware / software to be able for query an attached flash device to obtain information including:

1. The manufacturer and device identity.
2. The size of the flash device.
3. Timing parameters for accessing the flash device. E.g. the number of *dummy cycles* required between the address being sent to the flash device and the flash device returning valid data.
4. Which access modes the flash device supports.
5. The number and size of sectors, which are needed when updating the flash contents.

The Intel CSME firmware in on-die ROM can use the SFDP tables to query the connected flash device, and determine which is the fastest supported transfer rate supported by the combination of:

- The SPI controller in the Intel device
- And the attached flash.

Expect the power-up sequence of the Intel CSME firmware to be:

1. Send a *RDSFDP (Read SFDP)* command `0x5A`, and read the SFDP pages which are specific to the type of attached flash device. This will use a low `SCLK` frequency and with the command and address sent on the `SI` pin and data returned on the `SO` pin.
2. Determine the highest transfer rate to read data from the flash. This may vary according to which specific flash device is connected.
3. Issue *Fast Read*, *Dual Output Fast Read*, *Quad Output Fast Read*, *Dual IO Fast Read* or *Quad IO Fast Read* commands to read the Intel ME firmware from the data contents of the flash. These read commands differ in how many pins of the SPI flash are used for the command, address and data. The read command used and the `SCLK` frequency will be selected by the Intel CSME firmware according to the contents of the SFDP pages read above.

In response to the comment:

> Do you know which implementation Intel has chosen? –
> [Rand0mMan](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/366190/rand0mman)

Intel, from the point of view of the Intel CSME firmware, haven't chosen an implementation of where the SFDP tables are stored; that is down to the manufacturer of the attached SPI flash.

What Intel will have done is to write the Intel CSME firmware stored in the on-die ROM to query the SFDP tables of the attached SPI flash to allow multiple different types of SPI flash to be attached.

I haven't worked with designing boards with Intel processors to know exactly how the SFDP tables are processed by the on-die ROM. This answer is based upon writing some code to query the SFDP tables of attached SPI flashes for other devices.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know which implementation Intel has chosen?

Comment: @Rand0mMan I have expanded the answer to try and address your comment.